# Java Iterator not behaving properly

Tags: java, list, oop, collections, iterator

For some reason, the iterators here are not working properly. I debugged the code and it1 has elements. However, when it comes to the line before the return, is empty. Any hint?

```
private Tasks loadChangeStatusOnTasks(final Tasks updatedTasks, final List<Boolean> changeStatusList) {
        final Iterator<Task> it1 = updatedTasks.getTasks().iterator();
        final Iterator<Boolean> it2 = changeStatusList.iterator();
        while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
            it1.next().setAssigneeChanged(it2.next().booleanValue());
        }
        final Tasks tasks = new Tasks(new ArrayList<TaskDTO>());
        tasks.setTasks(IteratorUtils.toList(it1));
        return tasks;
    }
```

Comment: an iterator can only iterate once.

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information here to help you. We don't know what `Tasks` is, to start with. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (njzk2's assessment is correct, but you should fix the question on principle...)

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty'? Do you mean it has reached it end? `it1.hasNext() == false`? It is quite expectable.

Comment: Thanks both for your help guys. I think njzk2 could have the key. I am going to try that first and I'll update the code in a bit @JonSkeet. I have to say its a honour you saw this code, and a honour to have a chat with you. You're an example for developers my friend! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you reach `tasks.setTasks(IteratorUtils.toList(it1))`, `it1` has been exhausted: all its elements have been consumed already!

If you want to create a new List and assign it, just do:

```
return new Tasks(new ArrayList<>(updatedTasks.getTasks()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jean, but how can I respect the logic? If I use your return statement, it will just return the list as it was before isn't it?

Comment: Yes but what do you expect ``IteratorUtils.toList(it1)`` to do? The difference is that you called ``setAssigneeChanged`` on each ``Task``. So the content of the list is modified

Answer (score 0):

The iterator has already been iterated in the previous while loop and has no more .hasNext() elements. That is why the IteratorUtils.toList() will yield an empty list.

A solution could be to create the list first and loop over the list to set the assigneeChanged property from the other iterator.